# AppleScript - Scan for any updates to files in a specific folder

Tags: 3d, automation, applescript, blender

I need to write an AppleScript that

1) scans the files in a specific folder indefinitely.
2) If there are any new files or updates to the existing files it gets the root filepath as a string.

The idea here is I am constantly re-rendering files in 3d, and I would like to have a script that can detect any changes to the files and automatically pass an argument to my 3d programs.

Comment: Can you share what code you have?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method for this is to use a launchd plist to watch the folder. This is easy and you can google how to create a watch folder using launchd. When you create the plist file just make it run an applescript. Once you set that up your applescript will be run every time something changes in that folder just as you described in your item #2. As such you won't need the applescript to indefinitely monitor the folder because the launchd plist will handle that efficiently for you.

Good luck.